# Pycharm-Execution does not stop at breakpoints during debugging

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to debug python code in Pycharm. I assign a break-point on a line using ctr+F8 and then debug using the debug icon on top right corner.

However the execution does not stop at the breakpoint and whole code is executed.
I am trying to stop the execution at breakpoint and then execute the code line by line while checking the variable values.

What possibly I am doing wrong? It does not work on other code files which I created for checking.

Comment: Are you sure that your code reachs the breakpoint? is your code a python code or template code (like Javascript or HTML)?

Comment: The code is python code. it reaches the break point since whole code is executed at once

Comment: can you edit your question adding the snippet code and the line where you put the breakpoint? Can you see the red circle on the left of instruction?

Comment: Can you walk through the steps in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJtWxm12Eo0) to see if you have problems with the code and process it shows?

Comment: Did you select "manage.py" when debugging? Or go to manage.py then right click and click "Debug manage".

Comment: @Stelios is your line a variable assignment by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

See the answers in this issue [Unable to debug in pycharm with pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718760/unable-to-debug-in-pycharm-with-pytest). For me it was deleting the `__pycache__` directories because I had copies the project over from a different computer.

Answer (score -3):

In order to debug (and stop at a breakpoint) you need to use Run > Debug (Alt+Shift+F9), not Run > Run (Alt+Shift+F10).